# How to move everything inside a xml tag to a new xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a xml file input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
  </Parameters> 
  <Children>
          <Test Name="TestCam" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" />
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" />
                    <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" />
              </Parameters>
          </Test>
  </Children>      
  </Group>
  <Models>
      <Model Name= "NewPhone"> 
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

I want to move everything in a new xml file includes Group name and also the line with group name but without the children tag. So Basically everything but without the children tag in to a new xml file.

Desired Output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
  </Parameters>     
  </Group>
  <Models>
      <Model Name= "NewPhone"> 
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

I am new to python so i did some basic programming which just prints the child tag and child attribute. Don't know how can achieve the above mentioned desired output. Any help will be awesome. Thanks in advance

FYI - I have multiple same kind of file so it would be great if i can put a function which takes each file and moves everything except children tag.

Code:

```
import pandas
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io
from collections import defaultdict
from io import BytesIO

xmlDocument = open("input.xml", 'r').read() 
tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()  

for child in root:
print(child.tag, child.attrib) 

for parameter in root.findall('Group'):
print(parameter.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from a correction in your source XML:
*Model* element should be "closed", so add "/" before the termintaing ">",
so that it is written as:

```
<Model Name= "NewPhone"/>
```

To read the source XML it is enough to call:

```
tree = ET.parse('Input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

(*xmlDocument = open(...)* is not needed).

And now, as the main task is concerned, I see that you actually
need to remove each *Children* element contained in a *Group* element.

To do it, run:

```
for grp in root.findall('Group'):
    ch = grp.find('Children')
    grp.remove(ch)
```

Now when you print the "reduced" XML tree:

```
print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', short_empty_elements=True))
```

you will get:

```
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
    <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
            <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
            <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
        </Parameters> 
        </Group>
    <Models>
        <Model Name="NewPhone" /> 
    </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

## Multiple input files case

If you have **multiple** files to process this way, you should:

1. Write a loop iterating over source files.
2. Take the name of the current input file, without the extension.
3. Call a function which accepts the file name, parses the input file,
   removes "unwanted" elements and saves the "reduced" XML tree in an output
   file, which name is derived from the current input file.

An example of such a function can be:

```
def myDrop(fn):
    tree = ET.parse(fn + '.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for grp in root.findall('Group'):
        ch = grp.find('Children')
        grp.remove(ch)
    with open(fn + '_out.xml', 'w') as f:
        tree.write(f, encoding='unicode')
```

Comment: How can i do this for multiple files? Oh and by the way this works. Thanks

Comment: Write a loop iterating over your input files.
This loop should include: 1. Parse the current file. 2. Remove "unwanted" elements.
3. Save the tree, either back to the same file or to an output file, with the name derived from the current input file.

Comment: is that possible for you to put your thoughts in your above mentioned code?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I passed a filename myDrop("Input") and the above code saved the processed xml file as a new xml file which is input_out.xml. But i have a folder containing more than 50 xml files. How to i pass them? I tried to iterate over the files but it doesn't work. Any Idea how can we do that?

Comment: You should iterate over the directory containing your source files.
But if this directory is other than your default directory, then you should probably pass also the directory name.
Take also care to pass the file **name** (without the dot and extension), not the file object itself.